# How to add button to a previous, manual-created form?

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is: create a new form with a click (DONE and working, see code below), and then add some buttons to that new form. In this case, it's just one button because I need to make this work before adding more buttons. Should be pretty simple, but after following some Stackoverflow answers/YouTube tutorials/Internet tutorials I'm still not able to do it.
Actually, [the application] It's meant to be like a personal schedule, where I could track every activity or work to do, dispersed over several days (from monday to friday) and in each day you should find the different times of the day (morning/midday/evening).

My code is shown below (this code belongs to the button1_Click method of the first form, as you may notice).

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // día lunes
        Form SubLunes = new Form(); // new form
        SubLunes.Text = "Día lunes";
        SubLunes.Size = new Size(800, 400);
        SubLunes.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        SubLunes.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        SubLunes.ShowIcon = false;
        SubLunes.CreateControl();
        SubLunes.ShowDialog();

        // botones
        Button Mañana = new Button(); // new button
        Mañana.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 150);
        Mañana.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        Mañana.Text = "Mañana";
        Mañana.Click += new EventHandler(Mañana_Click);
        SubLunes.Controls.Add(Mañana); // should add button to SubLunes
}
    private void Mañana_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello, i'm new button"); // displayed when clicking new button
    }
```

This is how currently looks:

[Main form](https://k60.kn3.net/A73ED7314.png) ///////
[After clicking Lunes button (a new Button called 'Mañana' should be in there)](https://k60.kn3.net/E6270A7DF.png)

THANKS YOU in advance. See you later.

Comment: You should add the button before you show the dialog.

Comment: ShowDialog blocks all the code below it until that form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the form before creating the button :

```
Form SubLunes = new Form();
        SubLunes.Text = "Día lunes";
        SubLunes.Size = new Size(800, 400);
        SubLunes.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        SubLunes.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        SubLunes.ShowIcon = false;
        SubLunes.CreateControl();
        SubLunes.ShowDialog();

        Button Mañana = new Button();
        Mañana.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 150);
        Mañana.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        Mañana.Text = "Mañana";
        Mañana.Click += new EventHandler(Mañana_Click);
        SubLunes.Controls.Add(Mañana);
```

You should create the button before showing the form, like this :

```
 Form SubLunes = new Form();
        SubLunes.Text = "Día lunes";
        SubLunes.Size = new Size(800, 400);
        SubLunes.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        SubLunes.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        SubLunes.ShowIcon = false;
        SubLunes.CreateControl();

 Button Mañana = new Button(); // new button
        Mañana.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 150);
        Mañana.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        Mañana.Text = "Mañana";
        Mañana.Click += new EventHandler(Mañana_Click);
        SubLunes.Controls.Add(Mañana);

        SubLunes.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: My problem was fixed instantly. Thanks you, really appreciated.